# Return text after the third occurrence of '_'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my query currently:

```
DECLARE @x varchar(100)
SET @x = '110_DT_H55_VXELQ318_10Q'
SELECT left(@x, CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(@x))  )
```

This is the result I want: 
`VXELQ318_10Q`

Comment: I suggest that you create a readable title and include both expected and actual output in your question.

Comment: Who favourited this 'question'?

Comment: Someone as keen to find out what the OP actually means *"as I am"*, @HoneyBadger? :)

Comment: The best way to handle this is to stop storing delimited data like this. Do you always have 5 elements or can that vary and you want everything after the third one?

Comment: @SeanLange every thing after third one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the string into XML and grab the 4th fragment:

```
DECLARE @x varchar(100)
SET @x = '110_DT_H55_VXELQ318_10Q'
SELECT CAST('<x>' +  REPLACE(@x,'_','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[4]','nvarchar(100)');
```

This returns *VXELQ318*

The replacements will create an XML like

```
<x>110</x>
<x>DT</x>
<x>H55</x>
<x>VXELQ318</x>
<x>10Q</x>
```

The native XML-method `.value()` allows you to address each element by its position.

### UPDATE

The following will return all fragments with a position `>=4`

```
DECLARE @x varchar(100)
SET @x = '110_DT_H55_VXELQ318_10Q'
SELECT STUFF(
       CAST('<x>' +  REPLACE(@x,'_','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
            .query('for $nd in /x[position()>=4]/text()
                    return <y>{concat("_",$nd)}</y>')
            .value('.','nvarchar(100)'),1,1,'');
```

This returns *VXELQ318_10Q*

Comment: Wow that is slick Shnugo.

Comment: @SeanLange Thx Sean

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using PARSENAME. This assumes you don't have any periods in your data, if you do this won't work correctly.

```
DECLARE @x varchar(100)
SET @x = '110_DT_H55_VXELQ318_10Q'

select parsename(replace(right(@X, len(@x) - charindex('_', @X)), '_', '.'), 2) + '_' + parsename(replace(right(@X, len(@x) - charindex('_', @X)), '_', '.'), 1)
```

Comment: I don't know... Whenever I see a suggestion with `PARSENAME()` I get a strong urge to write a comment about the inherent flaws and draw backs ;-). But it will work, so +1 from my side :-)

Comment: @Shnugo I did at least comment that it won't work if they have periods in their data. And there are always way to get around even that pretty easily with a couple extra replaces. I like the xml thing you did a lot better.

Comment: The biggest draw backs - in my eyes - are the limitation to 4 parts and the inverse numbering...

Comment: @sean lange i want what ever text after three '_'s

Comment: Then use Shnugo's. It is more robust than this one for sure.